# Lighthouse: Failures: Site does not register a service worker

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I have service worker, my code to register service worker:

```
if('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register('sw.js')
    .then(function() { console.log('Service Worker Registered'); })  
    .catch(function(error) {console.log('Service worker registration failed, error:', error);  });
}
```

when I open the application in the browser, it shows the log-in browser's console 'Service Worker Registered'

Also, I can see the service worker in the chrome's inspect element in the application tab, service worker section display service worker.
see error

[image]

**Issue** :-

1. When I was tested with lighthouse and generate the report it shows:
2. A user will not be prompted to Install the Web App
   Failures: Site does not register a service worker.

my code is here: [github](https://github.com/baghel2/ng-pwa-master)

Comment: You are getting a console error in your sw.js file that may be causing the issue. Perhaps try to see if you can get that fixed.

Comment: Can you post code from your service worker file ?

Comment: code link: https://github.com/baghel2/ng-pwa-master

Comment: Hi Arvind, I've just tested your example with the Lighthouse and it looks like the issue has been solved (sw registered successfully), am I right?
How did you solve that, could you post an answer?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure your adding event listener the proper way, can you try following this guide : https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/caching-files-with-service-worker

Example they give for caching files on install looks like this :

```
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {
      return cache.addAll(
        [
          '/css/bootstrap.css',
          '/css/main.css',
          '/js/bootstrap.min.js',
          '/js/jquery.min.js',
          '/offline.html'
        ]
      );
    })
  );
});
```

This is causing your SW to break on install.

Comment: Hi SergejV thanks for you valuable comment, but I am writing the same code in my service worker: 
var VERSION = '2';
this.addEventListener('install', function(e) {
  e.waitUntil(caches.open(VERSION).then(cache => {
    return cache.addAll([
      '/',
      '/index.html',
      '/sw.js',
      '/style.css',
     '/Icon.png',
     '/fox-icon.png',
     '/icon-512.png'
    ]);
  }))
});

Comment: Can you try using self.addEventListener and not this.